# find errors in C function

Tags: c

This function converts a Boolean value to a string.
point out possible runtime bugs.

```
#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

char* bool2Str(boolean x)
{
char result[5];

if (x == TRUE)
strcpy(result, "TRUE");

if (FALSE == x) 
strcpy(result, "FALSE");

return &(result[0]);
}
```

Comment: Here's a hint to one of them: How long is a string containing five characters _really_?

Comment: Did you solve it eventually? Actually it doesn't belong here, because it is no question... Well, first there is no boolean in ANSI-C, secondly you'll overflow the buffer when copying "FALSE" to it and returning the pointer from a stack-assigned variable is fatal!

Comment: Offtopic: Definition of `jobs` tag: A job is a process executing in the background, or scheduled for later execution

Comment: It either is offtopic, or the jobs tag should be removed. Which it is. So it´s not offtopic anymore. Now there´s a question sentence missing. Okay. It is in the text anyway. So why did you guys close this question -- just due to formal reasons? Just asking...

Comment: @Vicky: I removed the company name from the question title; if you remove it from your comment here it'll be all but gone.  :)

Comment: Also, the blunt and ugly truth is: if you can't answer this question yourself, there is no hope in hell that you can manage a C programmer job. You'd get kicked out after the first day at work.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, you are a kinder person than me :-) OK, I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 11):

1. Buffer overflow: "FALSE" is 6 bytes including the null terminator which `strcpy` will dutifully write, but there's only space for 5.
2. A local temporary is returned by address from the function, making the returned value unusable (except to test it against NULL I suppose).
3. Values other than 0 or 1 will not write anything at all.  This pales in comparison to the other two bugs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Size of array result is too short - it should at least be 6
2. The array should not be a stack array. It needs to be either a static array or a dynamically allocated one.
3. There is no boolean type is C. Was this a typedef?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the caller calls this twice, with different boolean values, the second call will overwrite the first call´s result since it is the same variable (if it were static).

But, that variable result is not static, so the callee tries to return a pointer that points to a local variable which will go out of scope in a nanosec, which usually is a good source for a runtime error/bug.

Also, if I am right (not a C guru...), `strcpy (result,"FALSE")` copies six bytes to `result` while `result` can only hold five elements (indexed 0 to 4).